# How to generate signature in AWS from iOS objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please provide some demo or example for generate signature with iOS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html
Link doesn't contain any example in objective-c .

Answer (score 0):

You can refer AWS SDK for iOS which implements signing the requests. This is an example of using the AWSSignatureSignerUtility from AWSCore.

You can get AWSCore through cocoapods. Try

```
pod 'AWSCore'
```

in your Podfile.

```
    NSString *aString = @"a random string";
    NSString *secretKey = @"aKey";

    //unsupport algorithm, should return nil
    NSString *signature = [[AWSSignatureSignerUtility HMACSign:[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                       withKey:secretKey
                                                usingAlgorithm:kCCHmacAlgMD5] aws_stringWithURLEncoding];
```

For more information about the SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup-aws-sdk-for-ios.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I create authorization with help of signature. I try with many examples but not find anything. Also I read AWSSignature.m file in pod but not get proper way how to use it in my viewcontroller.

Comment: Can you tell us what's the use-case? Are you trying to add User SignIn to your app? Or are you trying to upload data to S3?

Comment: I have to use it in header in every web-service I use in application . see this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/hza7d1  , Maybe this help you to understand.

Comment: Most parts of the AWS SDK for iOS uses AWSCore which takes care of generating a signature and signing the HTTP requests. So it offloads the work of managing the http requests from the developer. For example if you want to connect to AWS S3 to upload data, you can use AWSS3 APIs which underneath uses AWSCore to sign the requests with the credentials you supply through AWSS3 APIs. Will that work for you? Or do you want to still create your own HTTP request and sign it manually?

Comment: AWSCore which takes care of generating a signature and signing the HTTP requests , Can you tell me with which function should I use for it in ios ? In AWSSignature.m I see one function "generateQueryStringForSignatureV4WithCredentialProvider" but don't get any example how to use it in any viewcontroller .

Comment: For example, Amazon Lex signs the request using the signature generated through AWSCore. You can have a look at the code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/91426a8faf782cbae1f1ee60f217adac5534047b/AWSLex/AWSLexSignature.m#L61

Comment: what is use of aString string ??

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *aString = @"***********"; NSString *secretKey = @"*********";

NSURL *apiLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://*********"];


AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *creds = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey: aString secretKey: secretKey  ];

     AWSEndpoint *url1 = [[AWSEndpoint alloc] initWithRegion: AWSRegionAPEast1 serviceName: @"APIGateway" URL: apiLink ];
     AWSTask *sign = [AWSSignatureV4Signer generateQueryStringForSignatureV4WithCredentialProvider: creds httpMethod: AWSHTTPMethodGET  expireDuration: 300 endpoint:url1 keyPath: @"***" requestHeaders:NULL requestParameters:NULL signBody:true];
```

Comment: for solution u need to use AWS SDK and import following  :-
#import <AWSCore/AWSSignature.h>
#import <AWSCore/AWSCategory.h>
#import <AWsCore/AWSNetworking.h>
#import <AWSCore/AWSService.h>
#import <AWSCORE/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to create `Authorization`

1. With the help of [AWS SDK](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCore/Classes/AWSSignatureV4Signer.html#/c:objc(cs)AWSSignatureV2Signer(cm)signerWithCredentialsProvider:endpoint:)
2. With the help of Open source code share [here](https://swiftpackageregistry.com/adam-fowler/aws-signer-v4)

For AWS SDK below function will be helpful

```
AWSSignatureV4Signer.getCanonicalizedRequest
AWSSignatureSignerUtility.hexEncode
AWSSignatureV4Signer.getV4DerivedKey
AWSSignatureSignerUtility.sha256HMac
```